# JavaScript create typing effect

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am trying to create a typing effect with some real-time voice-recognized text. I am using socket.io to pass the voice recognized data from the backend.

```
socket.on('transcription', data => {
  var finalDiv = document.getElementById('final_span');
  var text_area = document.getElementById('results')
  finalDiv.innerHTML = "";
  typeWriter(data, finalDiv);
  results.scrollTop = results.scrollHeight;
});
```

```
function typeWriter(data1, add_to) {
  var i = 0;
  var speed = 50;
  if (i < data1.length) {
    add_to.innerHTML += data.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter(data1, add_to), speed);
  }
}
```

Each time when some text is received from the backend, the codes should print the text to finalDiv.innerHTML with a typed-in animation. But when I run the codes, it produces an error of "data is not defined." What is wrong here?

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

```
function typeWriter(data1, add_to)
```

`typeWriter` defines `data1` as first argument argument but

```
add_to.innerHTML += data.charAt(i);
```

You're using `data` to grab the characters. Change that to `data1`.